# 'Address already in use' error in bottle Python Web Framework with paste server library

Tags: python, paste, bottle

Every time I stop and start the python script, I am getting below error 
in bottle python web framework using "paste" server library

```
"error: [Errno 98] Address already in use"
```

Python script

```
import bottle 
from paste import httpserver
import sys

app = bottle.default_app()

@app.route('/switchstate/<message>') def switch_on_off(message):
    response = message + '|$'
    return {'respone': response}

setattr(httpserver,'allow_reuse_address',0) 
httpserver.serve(app, host='192.168.5.8', port=9095)
```

Is there any setting to force server to use same port during restart?
Is it possible to stop a server and release the port also?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you stopping your server? And if you make a request to your server after you think you've stopped it, can you confirm that it doesn't respond?

Comment: No i am not stopping the server. Im directly stopping the program. Can you please let me know how to stop server gracefully so that it will release the port after shutting down?

Comment: Since im stopping the program directly web server also stops and don't respond to any requests but i can't use the port.

Answer (score 1):

The IP address in the `host` parameter must not have wildcards. It is the IP of your local machine the webserver should be listening to, not the allowed client IPs.

Also this error can be seen when there is already a process listening to that port/IP combination.

Comment: I tried with 192.168.5.8 IP address, but every time I stop and start the web server i get address already in use error. How to force  a web server to use same port as used during last startup. or is there any other way to stop the server so that it will release the port.

Comment: That IP will work only if it is configured on your system. You can try `0.0.0.0` to listen to all IPs. Then check if there is an other process on port 9095 or choose an other port. Also firewall rules can restrict port usage on some OSes.

Comment: 192.168.5.8 is my raspberry pi IP.  There is no other application using 9095 port. There is no firewall configured.

Answer (score 0):

Also bottle has a paste launcher that handles all of this for you.

```
bottle.run(server='paste')
```

In fact it has a myriad of launchers. I also suggest using cherrypy instead, it's maintained, threaded, and seems to me as more stable.